# Performance of Parallels VM from Bootcamp partition vs. VM on macOS partition

Tags: macos, windows, virtualization, parallels-desktop

Parallels allows us to run a Windows VM on macOS.

On older Macs, we were able to run Windows on Boot Camp, which was an alternative to a VM.

Interestingly, if we install Windows on Boot Camp we can, from macOS Parallels, run that Windows as a VM.

Now to the question: we generally say a VM will be a little bit slower than Windows running directly on hardware.

What about a VM from the Boot Camp partition vs. a VM on a macOS partition? Which one is supposed to be faster?

Answer (score 0):

### Comparable performance

According to [this Parallels document](https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/import-bootcamp/), performance for both a Boot Camp-based VM and a file-based VM are comparable (both get an "OK" performance rating):

[image]

### Drawbacks of running Windows from a Boot Camp partition

The table above also provides more information on the pros and cons of running Windows from a Boot Camp partition and in a virtual machine, so even if the former were slightly faster, **it may be more convenient to run Windows in a VM if you value easy backup and VM portability to another Intel-based Mac**.

Furthermore, note that using **Windows from Boot Camp may cause Windows or some of its application to ask for reactivation**, as explained in this [Parallels support article](https://kb.parallels.com/123314).

Answer (score 0):

When comparing running a VM from the Boot Camp partition with running a VM from a macOS partition, the first will be ever so slightly faster!

The reason for the speed difference is that in the first case, each read/write will go through your Windows guest file system (for example NTFS or ExFAT) and then directly to your block device - whereas in the second case, each read/write will go through first your Windows guest file system and then your macOS host file system (for example APFS or HFS+) - and finally to your block device.

The difference in perceived performance depends a lot on your particular use case. In general, it is not worth moving an existing setup to a Boot Camp partition only to get this (very marginal) speedup. I would seek such a setup only if you want to take advantage of the fact that you can actually boot that partition up in Boot Camp without virtualization.

Keep in mind that having the your guest file system stored on the host file system (instead of on a separate partition) typically makes it easier to dynamically change how much space it uses up on your drive.